# Android: ListView.getChildAt() throws null

Tags: android

Sometimes, when I call goToLast() it throws me a null exception in vista=lista.getChildAt(), it happens when the list is full, I dont know why I have this code:

```
private void goToLast() {
   lista.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

          lista.setSelection(mensajes.getCount() - 1);
          View vista = lista.getChildAt(mensajes.getCount() - 1);
          TextView txtMensaje = (TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txtMensajeLista);
          txtMensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should log lista.getChildCount(), see how many children the ListView has. ListView recycles views, which means it only hold limit number of views.

So if you want to get the last view, you should do something like this

```
private void goToLast() {
        lista.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                lista.setSelection(mensajes.getCount() - 1);
                // Figure out the last position of the view on the list.
                int lastViewIndex = lista.getChildCount() - 1;
                View vista = lista.getChildAt(lastViewIndex);
                TextView txtMensaje = (TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txtMensajeLista);
                txtMensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.getChildAt()` position is different to the position in your adapter. ListView recycles its views, so if you have more items in your adapter, than can fit on the screen it will not create views for all of those, but only the ones that are visible. If you want to update an item in the ListView you need to update it in the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`